# Cases when closing a connection after a non-empty "200 OK" is valid?

Tags: http, session, tcp

I'm debugging an issue between a server and a client where I have a hunch the issue is that the client is prematurely closing the connection, but I can't find the information I need.

My server is sending a 200 OK with no Close header and a non-empty Content-Length, but my client device immediately sends an ACK+FIN (No HTTP message) and closes the session. My experience with HTTP sessions tell me that this is not normal, but I need a quote from a standard that *says* it's wrong. A list of times it's valid to close a session after a 200 OK, for example.

For what it's worth, it's a CWMP ACS and CPE exchange.

Comment: Why could it be not normal? Client has got 200 OK response with content. If its glad with it why shouldn't it close? Why should standard impose a rule?

Comment: The standard defines when it's OK to close a session. If this is a valid case for it to be closed the standard will have language along those lines, which is what I need. Official information on the validity of this behaviour.

Comment: Check section 8.1.2.1 here  - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wrong. The client could be a browser and the user could have paged away, or back, or closed the browser.

The server just has to cope.